# My question has not had any answers. Is there something wrong with it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, unanswered-questions

It seems like something that someone must have encountered before but no one has even attempted an answer after two days. Am I too impatient? Should I ask it a different way? How can I draw attention to it?

[Multiple include paths (-I) for g++ in Eclipse and MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390273/multiple-include-files-using-eclipse-and-mingw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your question can effectively be reduced to just *"How do I add extra `-I` flags to my `g++` command"*...

You've already tried a number of things, and that's good. But you include an entire preamble on how you arrived at the problem before you actually ask your question, this is really not required. You also include a lot of information 2 or 3 times. This, again, is not really required.

Remember that in almost any writing, you want to include *the most important information first*; in this case, this is the *actual question*; adding more information is good, but do that *after* actually asking the question. You also want your question to be short and to the point; including extra information is good, but you can include *too much*, putting off readers. You want to make your question as comprehensible as you can.

I have edited your question to make it better, removing much of the what I thought was unnecessary text.

Comment: Carpetsmoker, thanks. I understand what you are saying. I wrote it as I encountered it and it makes sense to put the question first. I think your version of my question (above) is the most practical version of it, but what was (and is) going on in my mind is that I've found a bug and my hope was that someone had encountered it before, enabling me to let it go and find a workaround. I'm happy with what you did. Thanks again.